# How to get the javascript file (JS) path which is stored in application bundle to html file which is there in document directory

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview, nsbundle

```
I have one .js file named final.js which I copied as bundle resource I have a requirement like the html document which reads this js file should download at runtime and store it in documents directory. But the js file is not able to read by the html when I loaded it in webview, because of the path of .js file.

I tried with the solution like below, but not worked.
```

> `<script src ="./final.js"> </script>`

And finally I tried to copy the hardcoded path of application bundle like below, now it worked. Finally I come to know that the path is not proper.

```
> <script src ="/Users/unknownUser/Library/Application Support/iPhone
> Simulator/7.0/Applications/025EF3B6-F2E6-4162-8921-839D7D98FF58/HTMLGetdataTestApp.app/final.js">
> </script>`
```

Can any one tell me that how a html file which is stored in documents directory can read a .js file which is stored in main bundle with the correct path instead of hardcoded like above.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution will be copying the `final.js` file to documents directory.

Copy the js file from bundle to the document directory (where the html page is located) and set the path as:

```
<script src ="final.js"> </script>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, that I already done. But my one more requirement is final.js file should don't disclose to outside app. So I need to put it in bundle only.

Comment: @KarthikMitta: AFAIK , If you are not enabled the iTunes File Sharing option, o one can see the files inside the document directory.

Comment: Please explore about Ifunbox software, that can expose every thing even bundle resource files also, but my intention is atleast I can make that file safe from the people don't know about IFunbox.For IFunbox also, if deveice is locked with pin then no one can extract anything.

Comment: you are most welcome. please comment here If you get some solution for my question at any time....

Comment: @KarthikMitta: Sure, I'll do that. Just one thought why can't you use the delegates for copying the JS file. When the application become active copy the JS file, when it terminates or go to background delete that file. I know this is not a good solution.